# DOCX with PYTHON, is there limits of image that can be added without errors?

Tags: python, python-docx

Is there a limit in manipulating a docx document with Python ?
I used this mod :

```
pip install python-docx
```

I have a almost blank starting file called "TEST.docx"
When I execute this code, I have no issue when I open the output file :

```
import docx
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document("TEST.docx")
document.add_picture("test.jpg", width=Inches(7.0))
document.save("TEST_Output.docx")
```

But when I want to add lot of files (I repeat the "add_picture" line several times) :

```
import docx
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document("TEST.docx")
document.add_picture("test.jpg", width=Inches(7.0))
document.add_picture("test.jpg", width=Inches(7.0))
document.add_picture("test.jpg", width=Inches(7.0))
document.add_picture("test.jpg", width=Inches(7.0))
document.add_picture("test.jpg", width=Inches(7.0))
document.add_picture("test.jpg", width=Inches(7.0))
document.add_picture("test.jpg", width=Inches(7.0))
document.add_picture("test.jpg", width=Inches(7.0))
document.save("TEST_Output.docx")
```

Then, the script is correctly executed but when I open the docx with Word, I get an error message explaining that the content is damaged. If I click on "Yes", the document is correctly opened with the appropriate pictures..

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: does it happen with just 2 pictures ?

Comment: try using 2 *different* pictures

Comment: Yes, for the example I used the same image but in my personal project I have all different images. It works with 1, 2, 3, 4 images but I got this error after 5 images.

Comment: can you edit the pip install needed for it to run? (`NameError: name 'Document' is not defined`)

Comment: OK, I added the import. Can you reproduce ?